# error while running project in wamp

Tags: php, html

i have a website in php 5. I have downloaded all the files from the server and put all in my wamp (in a local system for changing some text). When i run localhost i got an error

```
**Internal Server Error
```

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.**

I don't know PHP5.

Does any one know how to browse my site in local system.

Please help me

Thanks ina advance

Comment: it's been a while since I've worked on Windows, but basically you right-click on My Computer, click Manage, and somewhere in there you'll find the system logs.

Comment: Have you worked with wamp before?

Comment: yes.i have worked on simple work

Comment: "Internal Server Error" could be caused by many things. You'll need to find the log files generated by Apache and find the cause. If you don't know PHP and don't know how to browse/find your files, perhaps you should consider learning the basics first.

Comment: is there an .htaccess file in your folder? if yes, try running your app by removing .htaccess to see if it works. And if it does, then check in .htaccess to see if there is something like Rewrite stuff in it. If yes, then from your wamp icon, go into apache -> modules -> url_rewrite (click it). Let me know if this works. Or best, you can paste your .htaccess codes in your question (if there is any .htaccess file). that would be very helpful to identity if the problem is in .htaccess .

Comment: RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule Products-cp_id-(.*)-category_id-(.*)\.htm$ Products.php?cp_id=$1&category_id=$2     

   

RewriteRule ProductDetails-pid-(.*)\.htm$ ProductDetails.php?pid=$1

Comment: @user1210570 ok So you can do the next steps explained in comments as well as in answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, by default, Wamp doesn't have `url_rewrite` enabled.

And your problem seems to be that of `url_rewrite` only.

Click on your Wamp Icon in the task bar, goto Apache -> modules -> scroll down to url_rewrite and click to enabled it.

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check if "**AllowOverride**" instruction in main "**httpd.conf**" file allows you to use .htaccess files.
If not, make it "**AllowOverride all**" and restart your WampServer.